# Difficulty proving chain rule for composition of linear map with function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove that for $f:V\rightarrow W$ differentiable at $\alpha\in V$ and $T:W\rightarrow Z$ linear, we have 
$$
d(T\circ f)_\alpha=T\circ Df_\alpha
$$
by showing 
$$
\frac{||T[f(x)-f(\alpha)-Df_\alpha(x-\alpha)]||}{||x-\alpha||}\rightarrow0,x\rightarrow\alpha
$$
but am struggling. Any tips on how to estimate the above difference? I am doing this just for fun so I would prefer just a hint.

Comment: I haven't looked at your question closely but I am assuming you are considering Fréchet derivatives (perhaps you can verify this for me in the comments). You should be able to prove that the derivative of a linear map is itself, and then prove a general version of the chain rule for a composition of two (nonlinear) operators. Combine the results to obtain the desired one.

Comment: @parsiad yes I am, I apologize for the ambiguity. I can definitely prove the derivative of a linear map is itself; I assumed that the proof of the chain rule would be much worse, I will tackle that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** I assume that we are working with finite dimensional vector spaces. Use the fact that there exists a constant $M \geq 0$ such that $\|Tx\|_{Z} \leq M\|x\|_{W}$ for all $x \in W$. If you are not familiar with this result, prove it by arguing that the expression

$$ M = \sup_{\|x\|_W = 1} \| Tx \|_{Z} $$

is finite.

Comment: that does it. Thank you for the lemma/exercise as well!